# "and" conjunction reduction, multiples adjectives modifying singular noun

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-number, conjunctions, conjunction-reduction

Is it proper English to say

> a psychiatric and an equine experts

to refer to two separate experts, a psychiatric one and another equine one?

In the following phrase, it's unclear whether we're speaking of one or multiple people:

> a psychiatric and an equine expert

Comment: You can't use "a" with a plural noun, so "a psychiatric and equine experts" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @alphabet So, the most concise way would be to repeat the noun "expert"? "_a psychiatric expert and an equine expert_"?

Comment: Or "a psychiatric expert and an equine one."

Comment: @alphabet — How does that disambiguate? *Jane is a psychiatric expert and an equine expert.*

Comment: @alphabet Your statement is about one person (so it seems); mine is about two.

Comment: "A psychiatric expert and an equine expert walk into a bar..."

Comment: I don't think there's any way to disambiguate them unless you put them in separate phrases. "We called a psychiatric expert and also an equine expert."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that English has many ways to reduce sentences to make them more concise, it isn't always possible. Often, you have to carefully express exactly what you mean to avoid ambiguity. This is definitely one of those situations.

- a psychiatric and equine expert. *<-sounds like one person is an expert in both fields*
- a psychiatric and an equine expert. *<-still sounds like one person!*
- psychiatric and equine experts *<-sounds like there could be several of each and still doesn't rule out the possibility that some could be both*

If you want to avoid the repetition of saying "*a psychiatric expert and an equine expert*", you could say something like:

> Two experts, in psychiatry and equines respectively.